# Combining a list of matrices into a single matrix while appending new values to previous columns

Tags: r, matrix

So I have a list of a 17 matrices that I want to combine into a single master matrix. However, I also want different values for an observation to be appended instead of being overwritten. For a simplified example,

```
m1 <- matrix( c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3) 
rownames(m1) <- c("x", "y", "z")
colnames(m1) <- c("a", "b", "c")


m2 <- matrix( c(2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2), nrow=3, ncol=3)
rownames(m2) <- c("a", "d", "e")
colnames(m2) <- c("x", "w", "z")


m3_final <- matrix( c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, "1;2", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2), nrow=5, ncol=4)
rownames(m3_final) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
colnames(m3_final) <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
```

My current thoughts are to run a for loop through the list so that each matrix is iterated into an empty master matrix to begin with, but I am having trouble with appending a new result to a previous result. My current error:

```
m1 <- matrix( c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3) 
rownames(m1) <- c("x", "y", "z")
colnames(m1) <- c("a", "b", "c")


m2 <- matrix( c(2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2), nrow=3, ncol=3)
rownames(m2) <- c("a", "d", "e")
colnames(m2) <- c("x", "w", "z")


m3_final <- matrix( c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2), nrow=5, ncol=4)
rownames(m3_final) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
colnames(m3_final) <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is advised to share data using `dput` instead of images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully now it's better with some code

Comment: Yes, thanks that's better but I don't understand what you are trying to do here. You are comparing column names of m1 with rownames of m2 and vice versa to combine the results?

Comment: What I want to do is stored as m3_final. Basically combining m1 and m2 together, but where there is another value for x under a, it is appended as "1;2" instead of being overwritten as just "2" shown in m3_error. The data I'm working with is all in character strings, but I thought it'd be easier to represent as a numerical matrix

Comment: There is no x under a. Can you recheck? `m1` and `m2` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the matrices. In m1 in the first example, you can see that under column a and row x, there is the value of 1. In m2, the value is 2. In the final (desired) matrix, 2 is appended to 1 to become "1;2" again stored under column x and row a. However, my problem is that instead of being able to do this, 2 overwrites the previous result and replaces 1 instead of being appended as "1;2". Hopefully this is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

One way (which may not win points for efficiency) is to flatten the matrices, bind them, and then reshape them back to wide format concatenating the values of common indices with `paste()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

list(m1, m2) %>%
  map_df(as.data.frame.table) %>%
  filter(Freq != 0) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var1, values_from = Freq, values_fn = list(Freq = ~ paste(.x, collapse = ";")), values_fill = list(Freq = "0")) %>% 
  select(Var2, sort(tidyselect::peek_vars())) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "Var2") %>%
  as.matrix()

  w   x     y   z  
a "0" "1;2" "0" "0"
b "0" "0"   "1" "0"
c "0" "0"   "0" "1"
d "2" "0"   "0" "0"
e "0" "0"   "0" "2"
```

Note that you mixed up the row and column names in one of the matrices in your example.